# First time SQLite3 user python 3, syntax error in print

Tags: sqlite, syntax, python-3.x

I'm working on a program that is able to make quizzes by exporting questions into a database. I've looked on the internet for a bit and it said that one of the easiest ways to import or export to a database in python is to use the SQLite3 plugin, so I'm trying it out.This is the first time I've used the SQLite3 plugin with python, and I keep getting a syntax error on the self.connection.commit() in:

```
def AddQuestion(self, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4):
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO questions
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (None, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer)
    self.connection.commit()
```

If I were to turn it into a comment by adding # before it, it would tell me that the print in this was a syntax error:

```
print ("Would you like to make a test? Or would you like to take a test?")
```

Maybe its my indentation, or am I doing something wrong?

```
import squlite3
class QuestionStorage(object):
    def _init_(self, path):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(path)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor ()

def Close(self):
    self.cursor.close()
    self.connection.close()

def CreateDb(self):
    query = """CREATE TABLE questions
             (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Question TEXT, Answer1 TEXT, Answer2 TEXT, Answer3 TEXT, Answer4 TEXT, CorrectAnswer TEXT)"""
    self.cursor.exeute(query)
    self.connection.commit()
    #self.cursor.close()

def AddQuestion(self, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4):
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO questions
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (None, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer)
    self.connection.commit()

def GetQuestion(self, index = None):
    self.cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM questions WEHRE id=?""", (index,))



print ("Would you like to make a test? Or would you like to take a test?")
testTaker = input ("To create a test, type Create. To take a test, type Take.")

if testTaker == "Create":
    testName = input ("Give your test a name.")
    testQ = int(input ("How many questions will be on this test? (Numeric value only.)"))
    testType = input ("Will this test be multiple choice? (y/n)")
    if testType == "N" or "n":
        counter = 1
        qs = QuestionStorage("questions.db")
        qs.CreateDb()
        counter = 1
        while counter >= testQ:
            Answer = []
            Question = input ("What is your question?")
            Answer[1] = input ("What is the first answer?")
            Answer[2] = input ("What is the second answer?")
            Answer[3] = input ("What is the third answer?")
            Answer[4] = input ("What is your last answer?")
            correctAnswer = input("Which answer is the correct answer? (1, 2, 3, or 4?)")
            Answer[5] = Answer[correctAnswer]

        qs.AddQuestion(Question, Answer[1] , Answer[2], Answer[3], Answer[4], Answer[5])
        counter +=1


else:
```

and then after the else, I'd have the code for reading the database to take a test.

If anyone can help me out with this, that would be great. Right now I'm just trying to get it to the point where I can run it in debug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to close the parentheses here:

```
self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO questions
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (None, Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4, CorrectAnswer)
```

Put another closing `)` at the end of the line.